# exclude files in tar.gz

Tags: linux, debian, tar, gzip

I want to exclude two files from a tar file.. But it doesn't seem to work

```
cd /var/www/public/api_test
tar -zcvf api_v2.x.tar.gz api --exclude "./api/distributor_test.php" --exclude "./api/library/Distributor_API.php"
```

Comment: try putting api last (after options).

Comment: no change in output

Comment: `tar -zcvf api_v2.x.tar.gz  --exclude api/distributor_test.php --exclude api/library/Distributor_API.php api` ?

Comment: create an answer! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try (in one line, I fold for readability)

```
tar -zcvf api_v2.x.tar.gz 
   --exclude api/distributor_test.php 
   --exclude api/library/Distributor_API.php api
```

- argument (e.g. `api`) should be put last
- you may use --exclude distributor_test.php (if you only have one file named distributor_test.php )